# jQuerymobile - Blocks & Splitscreen for iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, ipad

We are working with the framework of [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/) for the graphical interface of our iPad app, based on HTML5. Because we're creating an app for the iPad, we essentially need the typical split-screen like it is on ipad: A  narrow sidebar on the left side and the main content on the right side:

[image]

Now my question: I'm searching for the **code to create this splitted screen** and I do not find anything for this in the jquerymobile documentation– Did I miss it or didn't I understand it? If the code for the splitscreen doesn't exist on this website, where can I find something related?

Because I didn't find anything related to what I need, I tried another way to get this splitscreen. So I was working with blocks in the css stylesheets:

for explanation: In jQuerymobile documentation, I found a category with the name *"content formatting>layout grid (column)"* ( http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/content/content-grids.html) 
So I thought about creating two blocks for making the splitted screen. BUT I don't need a splitted screen with 50/50, but much more 20/80 or 30/70. I tried to change it into my stylesheet:

```
.ui-grid-x { overflow: hidden; }
.ui-block-x, .ui-block-y { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; float: left; min-height:1px;}

/* grid a: 20/80 */
.ui-grid-x .ui-block-x  { width: 20%; }
.ui-grid-x .ui-block-y { width: 80%; }
.ui-grid-x .ui-block-x { clear: left; }
```

the original was:

```
.ui-grid-a, .ui-grid-b, .ui-grid-c, .ui-grid-d { overflow: hidden; }
.ui-block-a, .ui-block-b, .ui-block-c, .ui-block-d, .ui-block-e { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; float: left; min-height:1px;}


.ui-grid-a .ui-block-a, .ui-grid-a .ui-block-b { width: 50%; }
.ui-grid-a .ui-block-a { clear: left; }
```

Does anybody know what I did wrong? **How to change the size of the blocks?** Is it the right way to do it like this?
Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use JQuery Mobile's Grid Layout and just override "width" on "ui-block-a" and "ui-block-b" to split screen as per your need.

for sample demo page checkout this blog
http://mdshannan1.blogspot.com/2011/08/jquery-mobile-split-screen-20-80-hack.html

Answer (score 5):

If you view the source on the jQM Demos page you can see they've added the div tags with the class="content-secondary". This is used for the side bar on a tablet layout. It will also stack if you view the same page on a mobile device with a smaller screen then a tablet.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="jqm-home" class="type-home"> 
    <div data-role="content"> 


        <div class="content-secondary"> 

            <div id="jqm-homeheader"> 
                <h1 id="jqm-logo"><img src="docs/_assets/images/jquery-logo.png" alt="jQuery Mobile Framework" /></h1> 
                <p>A Touch-Optimized Web Framework for Smartphones &amp; Tablets</p> 
                <p id="jqm-version">Beta Release</p> 
            </div> 


            <p class="intro"><strong>Welcome.</strong> Browse the jQuery Mobile components and learn how to make rich, accessible, touch-friendly websites and apps.</p> 

            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f"> 
                <li data-role="list-divider">Overview</li> 
                <li><a href="docs/about/intro.html">Intro to jQuery Mobile</a></li> 
                <li><a href="docs/about/features.html">Features</a></li> 
                <li><a href="docs/about/accessibility.html">Accessibility</a></li> 
                <li><a href="docs/about/platforms.html">Supported platforms</a></li> 
            </ul> 

        </div><!--/content-primary-->   

        <div class="content-primary"> 
            <nav> 


                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b"> 
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Components</li> 
                    <li><a href="docs/pages/index.html">Pages &amp; dialogs</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="docs/toolbars/index.html">Toolbars</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="docs/buttons/index.html">Buttons</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="docs/content/index.html">Content formatting</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="docs/forms/index.html">Form elements</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="docs/lists/index.html">List views</a></li> 

                    <li data-role="list-divider">API</li> 
                    <li><a href="docs/api/globalconfig.html">Configuring defaults</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="docs/api/events.html">Events</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="docs/api/methods.html">Methods &amp; Utilities</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="docs/api/mediahelpers.html">Responsive Layout</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="docs/api/themes.html">Theme framework</a></li> 


                </ul> 
            </nav> 
        </div> 



    </div> 

    <div data-role="footer" class="footer-docs" data-theme="c"> 
            <p>&copy; 2011 The jQuery Project</p> 
    </div>  

</div>
```